# Unable to set ant_home

Tags: java, apache, ant

I'm trying to set ANT but for some reason, even after setting the ANT_HOME and paths I keep getting the below error. Please help finding where I'm going wrong

ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or couldn't be located. Please set ANT_HOME

here are my environment variables:

```
ANT_HOME = C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.4;

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20;

Path = C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Users\HP\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools;C:\Users\HP\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;
```

I have my ant folder in C:\Users\HP\Downloads.

Comment: How do you try to set it?

Comment: remove semicolon from your ANT_HOME & JAVA_HOME.

Comment: wohooo ! That worked ... Thanks a lot Vaibhav Jain :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon from your ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME. It should be like:

```
ANT_HOME = C:\Users\HP\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.4

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
```